# APIs not visibile or administrable in WSO2 APIM 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, amazon-eks, wso2-api-manager

We have APIs visible in QA after we did add re_indexing = 2, but the same thing won't work in our STG or PROD Environment. I am not sure how to debug this issue or where is the actual issue. Since its the same setup in all our environments and only verified and test changes are deployed to STG and then to PROD.

Any idea why its working in QA but not in higher environments.

We have checked the logs and All the APIs are correctly being added to Synapse Conf. in STG and PROD .
Also when trying to create another api with same name, then we are getting DUPLICATE API already exists.

WE are using EKS Based Implementation and Deployment pattern-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can query from the solr data as mentioned in this blog post to narrow down the issue - https://medium.com/@sewmijayaweera/how-to-query-solar-data-16a7e051d5cf

If the data is not shown, the only possible option is to reindex the data in the upper environment as well.